# how to make it run?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have this when i try to run the flutter app .. i dont get it .. but i apreciate any help ..

I do have an issue which I'm working for a few days on. Many similar issues on StackOverflow and GitHub didn't matched my special case.

I'm building flutter apps and mainly debug them on iOS Simulator (Xcode). It works totally fine and never had an issue which couldn't get solved by litte bit of research.

But now I'm facing a problem that the debugging on iOS Simulator isn't working when the flutter project is located on other directories like OneDrive (for Mac).

Here the Error from Terminal:
[[i'im facing this problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUAkY.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpR6q.png)

this is my pubspec.yaml : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7eJR.png)

any help please ..i have to run it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.